# How to deserialize a Json object with an Android app

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to deserialize a JSon object with an Anroid app, but can't get it running. The intention is to read data from an asset item ("AllPoloniexPairs.txt"), which is the JSON objrct I'm trying to deserialyze and get "currencyPairs" from the Data part and put it into the spinner.

Below is (part of) my JSON

```
    {"BTC_BCN":{"id":7,"baseID":28,"quoteID":17,"base":"BTC","quote":"BCN","currencyPair":"BTC_BCN"},"BTC_BTS":{"id":14,"baseID":28,"quoteID":32,"base":"BTC","quote":"BTS","currencyPair":"BTC_BTS"}}
```

This is my code

```
    public class Data
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int baseID { get; set; }
        public int quoteID { get; set; }
        public string Base { get; set; }
        public string Quote { get; set; }
        public string currencyPair { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pairs
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public Data data { get; set; }
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(assets.Open("AllPoloniexPairs.txt")))
        {
            content = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        Pairs pairs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Pairs>(content);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner)FindViewById(Resource.Id.spinner2);
        List<string> spinnerItems = new List<string>();

        foreach (var k in pairs.data.currencyPair)
        {
            spinnerItems.Add(k.ToString());
        }

        spinnerItems.Sort();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem, spinnerItems);
        spinner2.Adapter = adapter;
     }
```

When I skip the foreach loop the app runs, but of course with no items in the spinner. If I include the foreach part, the application hangs.

I have tried several things now for the last couple of hours, but without any luck.

What could be the reason that the code doesn't run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well why do you reinvent the wheel google has already done it for you you can do it in two lines of code:

> https://github.com/google/gson

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyClass myClass= gson.fromJson(json, MyClass.class);
```

Well sorry for the delay was figuring your json data and it seems wrong to me and GSON you better use something like :

```
[
{
    "id": 7,
    "baseID": 28,
    "quoteID": 17,
    "base": "BTC",
    "quote": "BCN",
    "currencyPair": "BTC_BCN"
},
 {
    "id": 14,
    "baseID": 28,
    "quoteID": 32,
    "base": "BTC",
    "quote": "BTS",
    "currencyPair": "BTC_BTS"
}
]
```

You were using an object which has two objects in it.
That's not an array remember array should have brackets.
Now let's do this with the above json we have a class called MyClass let's say:

```
public class MyClass {
    int id;
    int baseID;
    int quoteID;
    String base;
    String quote;
    String currencyPair;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getBaseID() {
        return baseID;
    }

    public void setBaseID(int baseID) {
        this.baseID = baseID;
    }

    public int getQuoteID() {
        return quoteID;
    }

    public void setQuoteID(int quoteID) {
        this.quoteID = quoteID;
    }

    public MyClass(String currencyPair) {
        this.currencyPair = currencyPair;
    }

    public String getBase() {

        return base;
    }

    public void setBase(String base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    public String getQuote() {
        return quote;
    }

    public void setQuote(String quote) {
        this.quote = quote;
    }

}
```

Now in your activity use:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonOutput = "[{\"id\":7,\"baseID\":28,\"quoteID\":17,\"base\":\"BTC\",\"quote\":\"BCN\",\"currencyPair\":\"BTC_BCN\"},{\"id\":14,\"baseID\":28,\"quoteID\":32,\"base\":\"BTC\",\"quote\":\"BTS\",\"currencyPair\":\"BTC_BTS\"}]";
MyClass[] posts = gson.fromJson(jsonOutput, MyClass[].class);
Log.v("SteveMoretz", String.valueOf(posts.length));
```

You will get 2 by the Log which means you have two objects now you can use where ever you want.:)

Comment: I didn't know this wheel ;-)
However the deserialyze doesn't seem to be the issue. It looks like the foreach loop is causing problems

Comment: @Henk You're using var and foreach in java android?foreach is like for(Object o : list).And what's var are you using lombok?

Comment: I'm using foreach to iterate through the "pairs" list. With other applications (not Android) this works fine, however with this app it somehow doesn't work. Could you perhaps show me how you would (re) write my code using the Gson stuff? 
BTW the code is in c#, not Java

Comment: Yeah I was wondering what the language is.Cause there are no such thins in java.okay let me write it but it's so simple.Wait for the edit.

Comment: You're welcome don't forget to mark as answer and upvote :) I paused my own project just for helping you :)